# PyTorch: The number of sizes provided (0) must be greater or equal to the number of dimensions in the tensor (1)

Tags: python, numpy, pytorch, tensor

I'm trying to convert a CPU model to GPU using Pytorch, but I'm running into issues. I'm running this on Colab and I'm sure that Pytorch detects a GPU. This is a deep Q network (RL).

I declare my network as: `Q = Q_Network(input_size, hidden_size, output_size).to(device)`

I ran into an issue when I tried to pass arguments through the network (It expected type cuda but got type cpu) so I add .to(device):

```py
batch = np.array(shuffled_memory[i:i+batch_size])
b_pobs = np.array(batch[:, 0].tolist(), dtype=np.float32).reshape(batch_size, -1)
b_pact = np.array(batch[:, 1].tolist(), dtype=np.int32)
b_reward = np.array(batch[:, 2].tolist(), dtype=np.int32)
b_obs = np.array(batch[:, 3].tolist(), dtype=np.float32).reshape(batch_size, -1)
b_done = np.array(batch[:, 4].tolist(), dtype=np.bool)

q = Q(torch.from_numpy(b_pobs).to(device))
q_ = Q_ast(torch.from_numpy(b_obs).to(device))

maxq = torch.max(q_.data,axis=1)
target = copy.deepcopy(q.data)

for j in range(batch_size):
    print(target[j, b_pact[j]].shape) # torch.Size([])
    target[j, b_pact[j]] = b_reward[j]+gamma*maxq[j]*(not b_done[j]) #I run into issues here
```

Here is the error:

`RuntimeError: expand(torch.cuda.FloatTensor{[50]}, size=[]): the number of sizes provided (0) must be greater or equal to the number of dimensions in the tensor (1)`

Comment: i think you forgot to put your input tensors to cuda. try `b_pobs = torch.from_numpy(b_pobs).to(device)` and for your other input arrays too

Comment: oh shoot @NicolasGervais I pasted the wrong error. I updated the question, sorry! I did convert the input tensors to cuda, here: q = Q(torch.from_numpy(b_pobs).to(device))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`target[j, b_pact[j]]` is a single element of the tensor (a scalar, hence size of `torch.Size([])`). If you want to assign anything to it, the right hand side can only be a scalar. That is not the case, as one of the terms is a tensor with 1 dimension (a vector), namely your `maxq[j]`.

When specifying a dimension `dim` (`axis` is treated as a synonym) to [`torch.max`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torch.html#torch.max), it will return a named tuple of `(values, indices)`, where `values` contains the maximum values and `indices` the location of each of the maximum values (equivalent to argmax).

`maxq[j]` is not indexing into the maximum values, but rather the tuple of `(values, indices)`. If you only want the values you can use one of the following to get the values out of the tuple (all of them are equivalent, you can use whichever you prefer):

```py
# Destructure/unpack and ignore the indices
maxq, _ = torch.max(q_.data,axis=1)

# Access first element of the tuple
maxq = torch.max(q_.data,axis=1)[0]

# Access `values` of the named tuple
maxq  = torch.max(q_.data,axis=1).values
```

Comment: Thank you! It works, but it looks like its somehow slower on the GPU than on CPU.

Comment: Looping and calculating the results one by one is not suited for GPUs, they are mostly incredibly fast because of the multitude of parallel calculations they can perform. You need to avoid for-loops, as they cannot be optimised by PyTorch, and replace them with vectorised calculations, for example the for-loop can be replaced with: `target[torch.arange(batch_size), b_pact] = b_reward + gamma * maxq * (~b_done)`.