# Balanced KMeans: number of sizes provided must be greater or equal to the number of dimensions in the tensor

Tags: python-3.x, pytorch, k-means

I'm been trying to make a balanced clusters for my masther thesis using Google Colab (because I don't have a GPU) and balanced k-means Library (https://pypi.org/project/balanced-kmeans/), this is the process that I made:

1. Install the balanced k-means Library in Google Colab using this command:

   ```
   !pip install balanced_kmeans
   ```
2. Import a CSV file to my Google Colab instance:

   ```
   from google.colab import files

   subido=files.upload()
   ```
3. Create a Pandas dataframe

   ```
   import pandas as pd
   import io
   df = pd.read_csv(io.BytesIO(subido['prueba.csv']))
   ```
4. Then, changed the string data type to integer in the columns than I going to use:

   ```
   df["bytes"] = pd.to_numeric(df["bytes"],errors='coerce')
   df["bytes"] = df["bytes"].fillna(0)

   df["paquete"]= pd.to_numeric(df["paquete"],errors='coerce')
   df["paquete"]= df["paquete"].fillna(0)
   ```
5. Once I changed the data type, proceed to create a tensors (in this case 2 colums from the pandas dataframe) then stacked those tensors:
   import torch

   ```
   device = 'cuda'

   A= torch.cuda.IntTensor(df['bytes'].values,device=device)

   B=torch.cuda.IntTensor(df['paquete'].values,device=device)

   prueba=[A,B]

   X = (torch.stack(prueba,dim=1))
   ```
6. Finally I tried to create the clusters:

   from balanced_kmeans import kmeans_equal

   N=X.shape[0]
   num_clusters=100
   device='cuda'

   cluster_size=N//num_clusters

   choices,centers=kmeans_equal(X,num_clusters=num_clusters,cluster_size=cluster_size)

But unfourtanelly I got this error:

> RuntimeError Traceback (most recent call last)
>
> ```
> in ()
> 16 #print (W)
> 17
> ---> 18 choices, centers = kmeans_equal(X, num_clusters=num_clusters,cluster_size=cluster_size)
>
> 1 frames
>
> /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/balanced_kmeans/init.py in initialize(X, num_clusters)
> 16 indices = torch.empty(X.shape[:-1], device=X.device, dtype=torch.long)
> 17 for i in range(bs):
> ---> 18 indices = torch.randperm(num_samples, device=X.device)
> 19 initial_state = torch.gather(X, 1, indices.unsqueeze(-1).repeat(1, 1,X.shape[-1])).reshape(bs,num_clusters, -1, X.shape[-1]).mean(dim=-2)
> 20 return initial_state
>
> RuntimeError: expand(torch.cuda.LongTensor{[20839]}, size=[]): the number of sizes provided (0) must be greater or equal to the number of dimensions in the tensor (1)
> ```

I don't know if this error is caused by the tensor X having a 1 dimention, and in the library the initialization function create a empty tensor with zero dimension (I took this code from initialize method in the **init**.py):

```
indices=torch.empty(X.shape[:-1], device=X.device, dtype=torch.long)
for i in range(bs):
  indices[i] = torch.randperm(num_samples, device=X.device)
```

So Am I doing right? (I'm new using tensors) or there is a bug in the initialization function?

I already checked the solution from [PyTorch: The number of sizes provided (0) must be greater or equal to the number of dimensions in the tensor (1)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62163194/pytorch-the-number-of-sizes-provided-0-must-be-greater-or-equal-to-the-number) but doesn't work for me becauseI don't need a scalar value.